# XModem file upload example in C?

Tags: c, xmodem

Does someone have a code example in C for the receiving end of a file upload from hyperterminal using XModem? For Linux or other?

Thank you and best regards,
Bert

Comment: I have no answer to give, but I'll give the question a +1 out of sheer nostalgia - I haven't used XModem in 15+ years! :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's when they stopped shipping machines without a network card.

Comment: See rx of [lrzsz](http://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.menie.org/georges/embedded/xmodem.c?

Just 1 hop away from http://www.google.com/search?q=xmodem+c+code+sample.